# How to compare if an array is the same in reverse in C?

Tags: c, arrays, linux, compare, string-comparison

C language
I want to compare an array with it's reversed form and check to see if it's the same.

For example, arr1 = 5 5 8 8 5 5 
Reversed arr1 = 5 5 8 8 5 5

Then output would be: Array is the same in reverse.

**For some reason when I try to compare my two arrays, it ALWAYS says it is the same even if it is not.**

For example : 7 8 9 is entered. The reverse is 9 8 7, which is not the same as what was entered. However, my code says it is.

How can I fix my comparison so that the results are accurate? Please advise, thank you!

I tried using goto to display results. This is my code (function):

```
void function(int *arr)
{
  int j, c, temp, size;
  size = sizeof(arr);
  int old[size];
  int new[size];

  /*Prints original array from user input*/
  printf("Input Array: ");
  for(j=0; j<size; j++)
  {
     printf("%d ", arr[j]);
     old[j] = arr[j];
  }
  printf("\n");

  /* Reversing the array */
  c = j - 1;
  j = 0;
  while (j < c)
  {
     temp = arr[j];
     arr[j] = arr[c];
     arr[c] = temp;
     j++;
     c--;
  }

  /* Print Reversed Array */
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
  {
     printf("%d ", arr[i]);
     /*saved to new for possible comparison*/
     new[i] = arr[i];
  }
  printf("\n");

  /* Compare original array with reversed array */
  if(temp = arr[j])
  {
     goto same;
  } else {
     goto notsame; 
  }

  same:
     printf("Array is the same in reverse\n");
     return 0;
  notsame:
     printf("Array is not the same in reverse\n");
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has code has so many errors, first what's the size of the array you need? size = sizeof(arr) will return the size of array pointer which could be 4 or 8 depending on the machine. And where is the input part? Then while reversing the array, you are overwriting the original array. And finally, if (temp = arr[j]) will always return true as it is assignment, not comparison. You probably need if (temp == arr[j]) but that too does't make sense logically.

Answer (score 4):

You can't get the size of the array with sizeof. You should print out size and see what that value is giving you, it won't be the size of the array.

The reason you are always getting the "same" is that you aren't actually comparing values. You are assigning arr[j] to temp. if(temp = arr[j]) should be if(temp == arr[j]). I think you will find that it won't go to same anymore.

An easier way to solve this problem would be:

```
void checkReverse(int* arr, int arrSize)
{
   // Loop through the array until you have hit the middle
   for (int i = 0; i < (arrSize - i); i++)
   {
      // Check the element to the element in the same place counting from the back
      if (arr[i] != arr[arrSize - i - 1])
      {
         // If we find any that don't match, we know it's not the same and can return
         printf("Array is NOT the same in reverse.\n");
         return;
      }
   }

   // If we made it this far, they are the same
   printf("Array is the same in reverse.\n");
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your code with the following two points:

1. In your code, size means the number of elements in the array correct? so to calculate it correctly replace

`size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);`

`sizeof` gives you the memory size occupied by the array, so for the array of three integers, it gives 3*int size. To count the elements of an array you need to use sizeof(array) and divide it with the size of the data type.

2. You need to traverse in the loop and compare each element of the original array and reversed array to confirm is it the same not.

So you need to replace your comparison logic with :

```
/* Compare original array with reversed array */
  for(i=0;i < size;i++)
  {
      if(new[i] != old[i]){
          printf("Array is not the same in reverse\n");
          return;
      }
  }
  printf("Array is the same in reverse\n");
  return;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use recursion to solve this problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compare(int *arr, int p, int q)
{
    /* base case, if we are at or pass the middle point */
    if (p >= q)
        return 1;

    if (arr[p] != arr[q]) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return compare(arr, p + 1, q - 1);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int arr1[] = {5, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5};

    size_t array_size = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(int);

    int first = 0;
    int last = array_size - 1;

    if (compare(arr1, first, last)) {
        printf("Array is same in reverse\n");
    } else {
        printf("Array is not same in reverse\n");
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution to this question during an interview IMO: [Use a stack:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type))

step 1)
**racecar** -> push into stack -> STACK

step 2)
STACK-> pop from stack -> **racecar**

The input and output strings are the same, therefore the word is a palindrome.

As opposed to:

step 1)  **something** -> push into stack -> STACK

step 2) STACK-> pop from stack -> **gnihtemos**

The input and output strings are NOT the same, therefore the word is NOT a palindrome.